# getMeasuredHeight() of FrameLayout will return 0 First Time in android

Tags: android

final FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            XMAX = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
            YMAX = layout.getMeasuredHeight();

            System.out.println("==== The Y Max Is : " + (YMAX));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`. The view already has a width and height since it has been through a layout pass when that listener is invoked.